# Can't import dump file to Oracle18c(docker/macOS)

Tags: macos, docker, oracle18c

So I have a .DMP file that I want to import into the Oracle18c running on in the docker container on my macOS laptop. I managed to use `docker cp` to put the .dmp file in /home/oracle folder of the container. I then try to run `imp scott/scott@ocl file=/home/oracle/test.dmp full=y ignore=y` in the terminal under `SQL>` and `sh-4.2#`(which i started by clicking the exec button in the docker container gui).
However, all i got is `imp: command not found` this also happens to `sqlplus`.
What should i do?

Comment: You can start a terminal inside the running container by using docker exec and try to find if it contains imp command. If it doesn't contain imp command, you should check the container provider's manual.

Answer (score 2):

the imp command is the traditional import. This is what I did that worked for me in docker..

**1. run docker instance**

e.g docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -v ~/oracle_data/:/u01/app/oracle truevoly/oracle-12c

**2. get your your_ docker_container_id here**

docker ps

**3. copy the .dmp file to the dpdump folder**

docker cp /path/abc.dmp your_ docker_container_id:u01/app/oracle/admin/xe/dpdump

**4. enter docker instance**

docker exec -it your_ docker_container_id /bin/sh

**5. finally run the imp command**

imp system/oracle file=/u01/app/oracle/admin/xe/dpdump/abc.dmp  full=y;

**Hope this helps someone..**